# undefined local variable or method `owner' for FastlaneCore::Helper::AppcenterHelper:Class (NameError)

Tags: fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

While I am trying to distribute the iOS app to appcenter  Using Fastlane I am getting error like [!] undefined local variable or method `owner' for FastlaneCore::Helper::AppcenterHelper:Class (NameError).

```
+------+------------------+-------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
|    | appcenter_upload | 1           |
+------+------------------+-------------+

[11:49:06]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

➡️  appcenter upload error
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14907 [closed] 1 
    5 days ago

  You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your browser.
/Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-plugin-appcenter-1.0.1/lib/fastlane/plugin/appcenter/helper/appcenter_helper.rb:373:in `get_app': [!] undefined local variable or method `owner' for FastlaneCore::Helper::AppcenterHelper:Class (NameError)
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-plugin-appcenter-1.0.1/lib/fastlane/plugin/appcenter/actions/appcenter_upload_action.rb:173:in `get_or_create_app'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-plugin-appcenter-1.0.1/lib/fastlane/plugin/appcenter/actions/appcenter_upload_action.rb:201:in `run'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:256:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:50:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:235:in `block in execute_action'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in `chdir'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:154:in `method_missing'
    from Fastfile:51:in `block in parsing_binding'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:56:in `cruise_lane'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in `run!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:333:in `run'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:119:in `take_off'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/gems/fastlane-2.125.2/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/bin/fastlane:22:in `load'
    from /Users/capgemini/.gem/bin/fastlane:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Seems like a ruby error on your lane, but is difficult to know with the info you give us. Can you update it with the lane where you had the error? Also on this link you can find how to ask questions in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is the lane I have written in fast file for distributing in to the appcenter                      lane :distribute do    
    appcenter_upload(
        api_token: "api-token",
        owner_name: "my id",
        app_name: "ConferenceDialer",
        ipa: "./conf-out/conf-dialer.ipa",
        notify_testers: true     
    )
end

Comment: Make an effort to post here, please. Edit your question and add this code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following [link](https://github.com/microsoft/fastlane-plugin-appcenter/pull/88/).

There is a error in the source code which hides the correct error. I also experienced that I got:
`[!] undefined local variable or methodowner' for FastlaneCore::Helper::AppcenterHelper:Class (NameError)`

No matter what I changed. My "real" error was that the app_name (and owner_name has hard to figured out) was wrong. This [post](https://intercom.help/appcenter/articles/1764707-how-to-find-the-app-name-and-owner-name-from-your-app-url) helped me. Hopefully it can help you solve the real problem.